# What does PoS formula mean in Vitalik's blog post?

Tags: proof-of-stake

I don't understand what exactly the **PoS formula** means in Vitalik's blog post [On Stake](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/07/05/stake/) on the Ethereum blog:

```
SHA256(prevhash + address + timestamp) <= 2^256 * balance / diff
```

- Why do you need to multiply by 2^256?
- Why do you need to divide balance by difficulty?
- Does a miner create a candidate block only per second because timestamp is the only difference for new block?

Each variable means:

- `prevhash`: the hash of the previous block.
- `address`: the address of the stake-miner.
- `timestamp`: the current Unix time in second.
- `balance`: the account balance of the stack-miner.
- `diff`: an adjustable global difficulty parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for the author, but here's my take:

**Why do you need to multiply by 2^256?**

You don't *need* to but doing so allows you to think about it intuitively. 0 to 2^256 is the range of possible outputs of the SHA256 funtion. Therefore balance/diff is the proportion of that range that allows the "miner" to get reward.

**Why do you need to divide balance by difficulty?**

For automated global modulation of the reward range. This allows the latency between new blocks to be kept within pre-defined bounds, it therefore also influences supply of new currency.

**Does a miner create a candidate block only per second because timestamp is the only difference for new block?**

The prevhash would also be different as well for a new block, but yes; the timestamp resolution is seconds.